# How to Initialize the Spinner values with String array

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

I have a `Spinner s` object and I want to initialize this with array of String, after that i want set this Layout in `AlertDialog.Builder`

```
btnImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sub_activity_menu_item_addcart, null);
        Spinner s = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.sub_activity_mene_item_addcart_quantity);

        String[] items = new String[]{
            "1",  "2",  "3",  "4",  "5", 
            "6",  "7",  "8",  "9",  "10", 
            "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
            "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
        };

        /* HOW ? */
        // s.setValues(items); ????

        alertBox.setView(view);
        alertBox.setTitle("Add to Cart")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        alertBox.show();

    }
});
```

**Steps**

- I want to to get the `Layout` by using `getLayoutInflater()`
- After that populate `Spinner` values inside `Layout`
- In last I want to add this layout in `AlertDialog.Builder`

I have search this problem over the internet but did'nt found any suitable solution. Every body recomend to populate the spinner by using ArrayAdapter but i have no opetion for use ArrayAdapter

Comment: Besides going this way why don't you just make an alertdialog that contains spinner inside it? It would be much efficient also.

Answer (score 16):

Another way to populate a Spinner is to directly specified the String array from xml. use the `entries` attribute in your Spinner layout file

Your spinner

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
    android:id="@+id/yourid"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:entries="@array/context_view"/>
```

Your data stored in strings.xml for example

```
<string-array name="context_view">
    <item>ScrollView</item>
    <item>WebView</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 4):

You cand create an alertdialog with a spinner inside, just like :

```
final View update_layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.update_layout, null);
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Your title");


builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) update_layout.findViewById(R.id.sub_activity_mene_item_addcart_quantity);
String[] items = { "1",  "2",  "3",  "4",  "5", 
        "6",  "7",  "8",  "9",  "10", 
        "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
        "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeScreen.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

builder.setView(update_layout);

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How i can use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` with get layout using inflator ..?